# (Arduino - Jetson micro-ros) fork/exec /bin/arm-none-eabi-g++: no such file or directory

Tags: ros2, arduino-due

I try to run the Autonomeous Robot. So I must communicate arduino due with jetson nano.
This is environment

| HW | Architecture | OS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jetson Nano | ARM64 | Ubuntu 20.04 |
| Arduino Due | ARM32 | / |

ROS2: foxy

Arduino IDE: 1.8.19

Frist, I faced arm64 to arm32 upload error, but I solved by flowing this link.
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/installing-arduino-sam-boards-on-arduino-ide-for-arm64/550398

And I check the uploading example blinking code.

But I faced next problem.

> undefined refernce to 'rcl_publish'
>
> ...
>
> exit status1
>
> Error compling board Arduino Due(Programming port)

So I try

> Files -> Preferences
>
> "More preferences can be edited directly in the file"
>
> cd ~./arduino15/packages/per1234/hardware/sam/1.6.11-arm64

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/main/extras/patching_boards/platform_arduinocore_sam.txt > platform.txt
```

Then this error apear

> fork/exec /bin/arm-none-eabi-g++: no such file or directory

How solve this problem?

Please help me.

Try: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/main/extras/patching_boards/platform_arduinocore_sam.txt > platform.txt`

Expect: upload micro-ros example code to Aruduino Due

Result: Error: fork/exec /bin/arm-none-eabi-g++: no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I solved it by manually deleting folder

```
~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

and reinstalling "Arduino SAM Boards (Arduino SAM Boards (32-bits ARM Cortex-M3) with ARM64 support by per1234"

I think its because trying to installing 'non ARM64' package first creates an empty directory and when installing new version it perceives the compiler as already installed